# How to invoke multiple events on same button click in android

Tags: android

i am trying to make 2 arrow buttons on left and right ends of my activity where i have 5 icons/images, on click of any arrow button i want to display some text on the activity page along with highlighting the icon present on the page associated with the text. when i click the same arrow button twice it should display some other text and highlight another icon following the sequence. i do not want to change the activity every time i click the button. how should i go about it. Please help its a bit urgent...

Comment: What have yout tried so far? can you show us a piece of code?

Comment: you want single and double  click for a single button right ?

Answer (score 0):

see this [project](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM) on youTube basically it uses the same approche as you want except it switches only between images, you can amelirate it by using the View switcher for a views that contains imageview and text view, the source is attached too and the project switches between images using touch gesture too: